# Different orientation for iPhone and iPad in one storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I'm developing an iOS application, which is actually a wrapper for an existing web application. It adds some additional functionality which can only be achieved this way.

I finished designing the application using size classes and layout constraints. I used one storyboard for both iPhone and iPad. The problem is, I want the iPhone application to be able to only use portrait mode, while the iPad may only use landscape mode (there are different web applications optimized for iPhone and iPad).

Is it possible to do this using only one storyboard, or do I need to use two storyboards (one for iPhone, set to only portrait; and one for iPad, set to only landscape); hence duplicating my design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your info.plist file as code and paste this code:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Works well for me!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can do this in iOS8 there is very exciting feature named **Adaptive Layout** 
by which The same storyboard can now be used for both iPads and iPhones running iOS 8. There’s no need to keep per-device storyboards in sync with each other.

Here is the very good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) on this it will help you out.

Comment: Thans for your answer! I'm aware of this feature, but the problem is as follows. On iPhone, I want only portrait orientation allowed, and on iPad only landscape. As this is set per storyboard in the main settings of the project, I'm mot sure how to do this?

Comment: hmm then I suggest you to go with xibs file instead of storyboard as its very easy to control such situations in xibs.

Answer (score -1):

Just stick this in your App Delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```